# How to make Gradle flatDir read nested folders?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm using the Gradle local `flatDir` repository in the following way:

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'D:/path/to/local/directory'
   }
}
```

but it only searches for the first layer of files. I wonder if there is an option of telling Gradle to locate the dependencies all over the repository, so I would be able to organize my jars by groups and still make Gradle read them all without specifying the groups.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Maven directory conventions instead of `flatDir`?

Eg store jars like

```
myLocalRepo/com/foo/bar/1.0/bar-1.0.jar
myLocalRepo/com/foo/baz/2.0/baz-2.0.jar
```

Then in build.gradle

```
repositories {
   maven {
      uri file('myLocalRepo')
   }
} 
dependencies {
   compile 'com.foo:bar:1.0'
   compile 'com.foo:baz:2.0'
}
```

Comment: But what if I have too much jars for manually create this folders hierarchy? Do you know of any quick way of achieving this?

Comment: Where did your jars come from? Perhaps each jar has the group/artifact/version (GAV) in a text file in the jar. Eg under the `META-INF` directory inside the jar. If so, it's reasonably easy to write a script to loop through all the jars, read the GAV from each and copy them to a maven-like directory layout